# Microscopic understanding of Brewster angle

Tags: electromagnetism, reflection, dielectric

The textbook explanation is that, at [Brewster's angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brewster%27s_angle), the electric dipoles excited by the incident light can't reradiate to the reflection direction since it's aligned with the dipole moments.

Is there a deeper understanding of the microscopic physics picture? For example, is there an actual calculation of these electric dipoles induced by the near field?

Comment: Not sure where the "by the near field" part of the question comes from. The induction of dipoles is in essence the definition of a dielectric material - understand dielectrics and you have your answer.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't being precise about the near field aspect -- it will complicate the problem so please ignore it. I'm a published researcher working with dielectrics, and I think I understand them reasonably well. If there's anything else I overlooked, or if you know the answer to my question, feel free to elaborate.

Comment: There are actual calculations for lattices.  They support the microscopic picture that you present.  I don't think that there is any more fundamental understanding beyond what you already have.

Answer (score 3):

There are (at least) two ways to get at the Brewster angle. One is to consider little electric dipoles that are set oscillating by the incident light - as you mention and which I won't expand upon. Where I work, this is how we teach it in basic optics.

Then in electromagnetism we adopt the other approach which is to use the Fresnel equations ([Fresnel equations - wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations)) which are derived by considering the boundary conditions that must be satisfied by electromagnetic fields across interfaces. Namely that the components of the E-field and H-field tangential to the interface must be continuous (assuming no surface currents, and derived from Maxwell's equations).

One can then set up incoming electromagnetic waves incident upon the interface at an angle, but with two mutually perpendicular polarisations: one is polarised in the plane of incidence (the plane containing the incident and reflected light rays), the other perpendiular to it. Unpolarised light can be considered as an incoherent, but equal mixture of the two polarisation states.

When you apply the boundary conditions you get simultaneous equations (for E- and H-fields) and knowing the relationship between E- and H-field amplitudes for an EM wave and Snell's law of refraction (which can also be derived from these boundary condition equations), one can write down the ratio of reflected to incident amplitudes in terms of the angle of incidence - one expression for each polarisation state.

It is then relatively easy to see that at some special angle, one of the polarisation states (the one polarised parallel to the plane of incidence) has a zero reflection coefficient and hence the reflected light is completely polarised perpendicular to the plane of incidence.

Or the short answer - apply the boundary conditions for the electromagnetic fields of an electromagnetic wave at the interface, which are a consequence of Faraday's law and Ampere's law. Though re-reading your question I suspect what I've provided here falls short of what you are after.

Comment: Might be worth defining "plane of incidence" in the answer, since I usually think of "polarized parallel to the surface of the reflector". I assume "plane of incidence" is the plane containing both the incident ray and the normal to the surface of the reflector, right?

Comment: @Floris Correct. Though in this case (simple specular reflection), easier to explain as the plane containing incident and reflected rays.